# Heteroskedasticity: conditional or unconditional - a (critical?) distinction yet adjective ignored

Tags: time-series, heteroscedasticity

In *non-time series, regression models* when we say "*heteroskedasticity*" we almost always refer to "**conditional** **heteroskedasticity**". For example, the Breusch-Pagan test is a test for conditional heteroskedasticity. Robust standard errors are corrections for conditional heteroskedasticity. As far as I know, unconditional heteroskedasticity is of no consequence in regression analysis.

In *time series models* when we say "heteroskedasticity" we almost always refer to "**unconditional** **heteroskedasticity**".

- In *univariate time series models* in the ARIMA family, we visually test a series for heteroskedasticity by simply looking at the plot of the series across time - thus visually testing for unconditional heteroskedasticity. If there is unconditional heteroskedasticity in a series then it is not covariance stationarity (This answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/498901/198058) confirms it), whether that heteroskedasticity comes in clusters (suggestive of a GARCH model) or gradually increases/decreases over time.
- Even in *multivariate time series models*, we primarily care about unconditional heteroskedasticity. As long as all the series in the model are stationary, even if there is conditional heteroskedasticity, there is no unconditional heteroskedasticity, and hence no issues in hypothesis testing inference. [reference](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/498901/198058)

I am surprised that the common practice is to just say "heteroskedasticity" when in time series models we are referring to **unconditional** heteroskedasticity, while in *non-time series models* we are referring to **conditional** heteroskedasticity. The adjective seems critical, does it not?

Comment: It is critical, but this won't be the first time people are being careless like that. Consider also "stationarity" without any qualification to accompany it. On another front, unconditional heteroskedasticity is certainly of consequence in regression analysis, The question is whether we can do anything about it. One could argue that "unconditional heteroskedasticity" is essentially conditional heteroskedasticity depending on covariates we do not have data on, or not even an idea that they are affecting our model in the first place.

Comment: Excellent point. Definitely "stationarity" is another term people are careless about. Help me understand your point about unconditional heteroskedasticity. In what sense can it be thought of as conditional on covariates we do not have data on. We don't condition on anything, by definition, so I am confused about that bit.

Comment: Don't forget the real world. There is nothing to prevent the real world from hosting a relation like $y = xb + u$ with $var(u|x) = var(u)$ but for some other variables $z$ $var(u|z) = h(z)$ where $h()$ is some positive function. And $z$ may vary with the variables in the model. And you may not have data on $z$ or you may even not suspect that $z$ affect the variance of $u$.

Comment: Got it now. Thank you for that clarification.